# How to define namedqueries.xml in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot

I am migrating an old version of Spring application to latest Spring Boot application.In old Spring application we are using hbm.xml and orm.xml and persistance.xml along with Namedqueries.xml files.

I have converted all xml files to respective beans but want to use Namedqueries.xml as it is I don't want to convert those queries using annotation. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use orm.xml that allows you to define JPA mappings in XML. This approach is equivalent and overrides annotations.

<entity class="com.example.Employee">
    <table name="Employee.findAll" />
    <named-query name="findAll">
        <query><![CDATA[
          SELECT e
          FROM Employee e
        ]]></query>
    </named-query>
</entity>
```

Comment: I dont want to use XML looking options like defining Namedquery.xml in class path and Spring Boot Hibernate will auto detect?

Comment: Put all named queries that in Namedquery.xml file in the orm.xml at META-INF folder. For all class JPA mapping you can use annotations. The SpringBoot will get your named queries in the orm.xml file.